# How Can I resolve this assembly reference issue in ASP.Net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm going to run the ASP.net website on Visual Studio 2019
It used the ASP.NET MVC framework With NHibernate.
The solution has 5 projects including Domain, UI, Media, Resources, ...
When building the solution, gets these errors.

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'MediaServices' does not exist in the namespace 'ESK.Business' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  Pazar.Domain    E:\project\esk\src\Domain\ESK.Domain\Subscribers\MoveMediaCommand.cs

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Resources' does not exist in the namespace 'ESK' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   ESK.Domain  E:\project\esk\src\Domain\ESK.Domain\BackgroundTasks\BetterTask\Commands\TaskNotifyGalleryOnCreateEmailCommand.cs

The first error is concerned soap service but I can't resolve it.
The second error is concerned the Resources project that has the App_GlobalResources package.

Please help me to fix these errors. I think it's ABC in programming.

Comment: I guess, you need to add a project reference per project.

Comment: I added references to project, but same.

Comment: Then you need to add `using ...` statements in the files where you have errors.

Comment: The error occurs on the 'using' line.  `using ESK.Resources.App_GlobalResources;`, `using ESK.Business.MediaServices;`

Comment: A screenshot of your Solution Explorer will be helpful.

Comment: From where did you get the source code? If it started as a broken solution, you won't easily fix it and should start from scratch.

Comment: I've fixed the first error now.  Updated service references.